# Can I deploy my Firebase Hosting webpage using gcloud instead of the Firebase CLI?

Tags: firebase, gcloud, firebase-hosting

I was previously using the Firebase CLI to deploy my webpage hosted in Firebase. After Node.js was upgraded to version 8, I'm not able to use the tool anymore. For functions (`HTTP`), I'm now using the `gcloud` command-line tool interface for Cloud Functions.

Is there any `gcloud` command-line tool command to deploy hosted webpages?

Comment: The Firebase CLI works fine with node 8 and above. There is no gcloud CLI for deploying to Firebase Hosting.

Comment: How useful is [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/) command?